# List posts of terms but exclude one term

Tags: wp-query, advanced-taxonomy-queries, tax-query

I have a Custom Post Type for "Products" with a Custom Taxonomy of "Product Line." I've set up a page to list out the Products by their Product Line. However, we're also using a Product Line of "Featured Products" to use on the Homepage only. We do not want "Featured Products" to display within the "All Products" page. I have the following loop.

```
  <?php 
    $post_type = 'products';
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post_type );

    foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC'));

        if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $args = array(
                    'post_type'           => $post_type,
                    'orderby'             => 'date',
                    'order'               => 'ASC',
                    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                    'post_status'         => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page'      => - 1,
                    'tax_query'           => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'    => $taxonomy,
                            'field'       => 'slug',
                            'terms'       => $term->slug,
                            'operator'    => 'IN'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'    => $taxonomy,
                            'field'       => 'slug',
                            'terms'       => 'featured-products',
                            'operator'    => 'NOT IN'
                        )
                    )
                );
                $my_query = null;
                $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
                    echo '<div class="resource"><h2>' . $term->name . '</h2>';

                        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

                            <ul>
                              <li>
                                <div class="resource_image_helper">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_field('mobile_image'); ?>"></a>
                                </div>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                <ul>
                                    <?php
                                      // Grab the title and change for slug
                                        $title    = get_the_title();
                                        $stripped = sanitize_title_with_dashes($title);

                                      $literature = do_shortcode('[downloads category='.$stripped.']');
                                      $photos     = get_field('tab_photos');
                                    ?>  

                                    <?php if(!empty($photos)): ?> 
                                        <li>
                                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Photos</a>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                        <li>
                                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Videos</a>
                                        </li>

                                    <?php if(!empty($literature)): ?> 
                                        <li>
                                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Literature</a>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                </ul>
                              </li>
                            </ul>

                        <?php
                        endwhile; 
                    echo '</div>';
                } // END if have_posts loop
                wp_reset_query(); 
            } // END foreach $terms
        }
    }
  ?>
```

The problem I'm having is with the `tax_query` portion. I do not want to show the "Featured Products" term, which I've done. But with this code, it doesn't show any products that are withing "Featured Products." I still need the Products to show under other Product Line terms, I just need the Featured Products term to not be displayed. Any ideas?

Comment: You know, you could simply use post meta for featured posts like everyone does to distinguish special posts. That is not a loop. You could just perform one query and then sort and manipulate your resulting array using php functions to run your for loop. Right now you are performing (all the taxonomies * all the terms) number of queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you set up looks, but it does seem that you have a lot of taxonomies registered to your post type, so I don't think it will be very viable to use the the exclude parameter in `get_terms()` to exclude the specific term.

What I would suggest is, inside your `foreach` loop before you declare your query arguments, add the following line

```
if ( $term->slug == 'featured-products' )
    continue;
```

This will skip the specific term from being queried. You should also delete the second array inside your `tax_query` where you exclude the featured products term. This will ensure that you still get featured products under the other terms

Just a note, your query is quite expensive and you are hitting the db quite hard. I would suggest that you look at caching the results to optimize the query. You can also have a look at transients